# Rails: Guard seems to be deleting seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I am using Test::Unit to test my rails application, and everything is fine when I do "rake test". However, running "bundle exec guard", I get a lot of failures and errors (linked to the seeds needed in my application), and my databases are all empty (no seed data).

What is it that Guard does differently? Is there something that I need to add in my Guardfile?

My Guardfile looks like this (I think this is the default when you do guard init):

```
guard :test do

  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')  { "test" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.+)\.rb$})                   { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)\.rb$})              { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/views/.+\.rb$})                      { "test/integration" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb') { ["test/functional", "test/integration"] }
end
```

Comment: Which guard(s) are you running? Are you using spork?

Comment: No, I don't use spork. As for which Guard I am running, I think it's 'test'. I have edited the question to add my Guardfile.